# How to bound a circle inside an ellipse?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, graphics

The title for this post was quite hard to think of, so if you can think of a more descriptive title please tell me. Anyway, my problem is quite specific and requires some simple maths knowledge. I am writing a C# WinForms application which is a bit like the old 'xeyes' Linux application. It basically is a set of eyes which follow around your mouse cursor. This may sound easy at first, however can get rather complicated if you're a perfectionist like me :P. This is my code so far (only the paint method, that is called on an interval of 16).

```
int lx = 35;
int ly = 50;
int rx;
int ry;

int wx = Location.X + Width / 2;
int wy = Location.Y + Height / 2;

Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;

// Calculate X

float tempX = (mx - wx) / (float)(bounds.Width / 2);

// Calculate Y

float tempY = (my - wy) / (float)(bounds.Height / 2);

// Draw eyes

e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, 10, 10, 70, 100);
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, 90, 10, 70, 100);

// Draw pupils (this only draws the left one)

e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, lx += (int)(25 * tempX), ly += (int)(40 * tempY), 20, 20);
```

Now this does work at a basic level, however sometimes this can happen if the user puts the cursor at 0,0.

[image: The pupil can exit the main eye.]

Now my question is how to fix this? What would the IF statement be to check where the mouse pointer is, and then reduce the pupil X depending on that?

Thanks.

**Edit:** This is where I get the mouse positions (`my` and `mx`):

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mx = Cursor.Position.X;
    my = Cursor.Position.Y;

    Invalidate();
}
```

The timer is started in the eyes_Load event and the interval is 16.

**Edit 2:** Final solution: http://pastebin.com/fT5HfiQR

Comment: Is `mx` and `my` the MousePosition?  Your code isn't showing that.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Hmm, ok, 0, 0, is top left and your eyeball is top left.  Not sure I see the issue.

Comment: I want to know how to avoid the pupil exiting the main grey eye. Somehow I need to adjust the X position depending on the mouse Y. (My full code: http://pastebin.com/j8PeGAPX)

Comment: OK, now I see (ha-ha).

Comment: I'd have changed it to "How to bound a circle inside an ellipse". but that's just me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modelling the eyeball as the following ellipse:

[image]

Its equation is:

[image]

And that of the line joining its center and the cursor:

[image]

(don't worry about the singularity)

We can then solve to get the intersection point:

[image]

Where

[image]

Now you can calculate the distance to the eyeball's edge, by dividing the distance from the center to the cursor by sigma. What remains is just interpolating to cap the position of the pupil:

[image]

[image]

The `if` statement you want is then

[image]

---

(N.B. for math-mo's out there the above was a slight simplification, which assumes your ellipse is not too narrow; the *exact* solution is non-analytical)

---

EDIT: my tests in VB.NET:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT 2: C# port

```
PointF Bound(double xc, double yc, double w, double h, double xm, double ym, double r)
{
   double dx = xm - xc, dy = ym - yc;
   if (Math.Abs(dx) > 0.001 && Math.Abs(dy) > 0.001) 
   {
      double dx2 = dx * dx, dy2 = dy * dy;
      double sig = 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(dx2 / (w * w * 0.25) + dy2 / (h * h * 0.25));
      double d = Math.Sqrt(dx2 + dy2), e = d * sig;
      if (d > e - r)
      {
         double ratio = (e - r) / d;
         return new PointF((float)(xc + dx * ratio),
                        (float)(yc + dy * ratio));
      }
   }
   return new PointF((float)xm, (float)ym);
}
```

- `xc`, `yc`: Center coordinates of the ellipse
- `w`, `h`: Width and height of the ellipse
- `xm`, `ym`: Mouse coordinates
- `r`: Radius of the circle you wanna constrain (the pupil)
- Returns: The point where you wanna place the center of the circle

---

EDIT 3: Many thanks to Quinchilion for the following optimization (gawd damn this smacked me hard in the face)

```
PointF Bound(double xc, double yc, double w, double h, double xm, double ym, double r)
{
    double x = (xm - xc) / (w - r);
    double y = (ym - yc) / (h - r);
    double dot = x*x + y*y;
    if (dot > 1) {
        double mag = 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(dot);
        x *= mag; y *= mag;
    }
    return new PointF((float)(x * (w - r) + xc), (float)(y * (h - r) + yc));
}
```

Comment: This will take a while to test. I will accept it (or not) when I have completed testing it. Thank you for putting the time in to answer.

Comment: Mind posting the exact VB.NET code? I do not know VB.NET very well but I would be able to understand it better from reading code, not equations. Thanks.

Comment: I do not mind about having the exact answer, of course this is to help the community, not only me. I could easily just pull out the logic from VB.NET, as I never planned on copying the code word for word.

Comment: Where are the variables `xc`, `yc`, `w`, `h`, `xm`, `ym` and `r` coming from? (from your C# port)

Comment: @odixon they are the parameters as named in the equations; see edit

Comment: So what is this method returning? By ellipse do you mean the eye or the pupil?

Comment: @odixon ellipse = eyeball (the whole white thing); this method returns the position of the pupil you want (black circle in test scrnshots)

Comment: I assume I am calling and then using this correctly? `PointF testPos = Bound(10, 10, 70, 100, mx, my, 10); e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, testPos.X, testPos.Y, 20, 20);`

Comment: @odixon looks ok; the `FillEllipse` is wrong though - it starts from the top-left corner, so you wanna do `..., testPos.X - 10, testPos.Y - 10, ...`; also I'd set `xc, yc` to 100, 100 cos in this form part of the ellipse will be outside the draw area

Comment: I don't think I know what you mean? This is the code that draws the eyes: `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, 10, 10, 70, 100);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, 90, 10, 70, 100);`

Comment: @odixon ah but the second and third parameters are the _top left_ coordinates, _not_ the center. put `... -25, -25 ...` for the first one (10 - 70 / 2), and similarly for the second `... 55, -25, ...`

Comment: For the "first" parameter, do you mean this? `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, 10 - 70 / 2, 10, 70, 100);`, because that would just send it off the left side.

Comment: @odixon yes and don't forget to correct the second one as well; and obviously just put -25 :D

Comment: @odixon hooray! now do the second one

Comment: So if I set the second one to -25 and -25 it just will overlay the first one... http://i.imgur.com/P5AgBnt.png `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, -25, -25, 70, 100);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, -25, -25, 70, 100);`

Comment: @odixon no i mean correct them correspondingly: subtract half the width from the center X to get the top left X, and similarly for the Y; so you want 55, -25 for the second eye

Comment: @odixon also I suggest you move the ellipses so you don't encounter this off-screen clipping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113778/discussion-between-odixon-and-willywonkadailyblah).